# Validation attribute in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a problem in a XSD,I need to validate an XML in XSD, but I have trouble to declare the **attribute**.

The attribute is:

```
<xs:attribute name='currency' type='xs:string'/>
```

Code in XML:

```
<price currency="€">30,65</price>
```

Code XSD:

```
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="information"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="data"/>
<xs:element type="complexPrice" name="price"/>
<xs:complexType name="complexPrice">
  <xs:attribute name='currency' type='xs:string'/>
</xs:complexType>
```

This is error:

*S4s-elt-must-match.1: The Content Of 'price' Must Match (annotation?, (simpleType | ComplexType)?, (unique | Key | Keyref)*)). A Problem Was Found Starting At: Attribute.*

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to define a "complex type with simple content", something like this:

```
<xs:element name="price">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:attribute name="currency" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```